# Eager Loading a Structure and descendants

Tags: structure, eager-loading

In looking at the the `BaseElementModel:getDescendants()` method and saw it checks for eager loading elements named 'descendants.'

```
// Eager-loaded?
if ($this->hasEagerLoadedElements('descendants'))
{
    return $this->getEagerLoadedElements('descendants');
}
```

I added `with` and the `descendants` condition to a Structure and the page is now loading with a few less queries.

```
{% set entries = craft.entries({
    section: 'sectionHandle',
    limit: null,
    with: [
        'descendants'
    ]
}) %}
```

Can anybody explain what is happening here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Craft [2.6.2789](https://craftcms.com/changelog#build2789) added this feature, which is seems you've reverse engineered. :)

> It is now possible to eager-load Structure entries' and categories' descendants using the `'descendants'` handle.

Comment: Easy points! And I see I should have searched the changelog, not the docs ;-)